# How to add every couple row of matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, addition

Assume I have a matrix like

```
a = np.array([[[ 1,  2], [ 3,  4]],
              [[ 5,  6], [ 7,  8]],
              [[ 9, 10], [11, 12]],
              [[13, 14], [15, 16]]])
```

The shape is `(4, 2, 2)`. I want to sum the first two and the 2nd two matrices to each other. Final output size should have shape `(2, 2, 2)` and the output should be

```
output = np.array([[[ 6,  8], [10, 12]],
                   [[22, 24], [26, 28]]])
```

You can see my attempt below:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[[ 1,  2], [ 3,  4]],
              [[ 5,  6], [ 7,  8]],
              [[ 9, 10], [11, 12]],
              [[13, 14], [15, 16]]])

output = np.add(a[:2], a[2:])
```

Comment: Please fix your variable names. One line calls it `Input`, which is not very pythonic, the other `a`. Pick one.

Comment: Also, `np.add` is just `+` in this context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break the first dimension up into two using a reshape, sum along the second axis:

```
a.reshape(2, 2, *a.shape[1:]).sum(axis=1)
```

Your current approach is equivalent to `a.reshape(2, 2, *a.shape[1:]).sum(axis=0)`. The correct way would be to slice every other row of the entire array, rather than every other block of the entire array:

```
a[::2] + a[1::2]
```

The latter approach does not generalize well. If you had to add up say every block of seven, you would get

```
a[::7] + a[1::7] + a[2::7] + a[3::7] + ... + a[6::7]
```

The former approach is quite flexible, however:

```
a.reshape(-1, 7, *a.shape[1:]).sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I have a matrix a=np.random.randint(5,size=(140,64,1,60,60)) and want to add the first 7 matrices and second 7 and so on... the final output size should have the shape (20,64,1,60,60).

Comment: @Aras. Please make an effort to understand what I've written here and how it works. Make an effort to work out the slicing on your own. If that doesn't work, ask another question.

Comment: I suppose this should be correct: b=a.reshape(20,7, *a.shape[1:]).sum(axis=1)

Comment: @Aras. I think you got the gist of it :) I'm glad you took the time to work through it.

Comment: Another quick question: what if one of matrices, i.e., the last one of (140,64,1,60,60)), instead of size 64 is 8. Actually, that is batch size which usually differs in last matrix. It raised with error "operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (64,1,600,600) (8,1,600,600)"